# Awesomium сохранение изображения на уже загруженной странице

Tags: c#, awesomium

Как можно обратиться к изображению на уже загруженной странице в Awesomium и позже сохранить его, мб у него есть какое-то хранилище ресурсов или еще что-то?

Comment: SO [английский](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31916266/7482894)

Comment: У изображения нету Id